# Static HTML Elements loads before data fetch in Vue Application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, fetch-api

I'm using VueJS and VueRouter to create my application. My problem is that when I'm fetching data the static HTML elements used on the Vue Component load before the actual fetch, causing empty forms and tables to be displayed before data is fetched. I call my fetch method from the created() lifecycle hook, so the result is confusing me. Here are my code so far:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>My Data length: {{fetchedData.length}}</h1>
    <li v-for="value in fetchedData">{{value}}</li>
  </div>
</template>


export default {
  name: "MyVueComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      fetchedData: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getData() {
       await fetch('https://cli-vue-application.herokuapp.com/user/getUser', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      })
          .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
          }).then(function (data) {
            this.fetchedData= data
          }.bind(this));
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getData();
  }
}
```

The data is fetched correctly, but the h1 element displays first and the length is "0" for the first couple of seconds, because the fetch happnds after the static HTML is loaded as explained above.

Comment: what is the question? that is expected behaviour

Comment: The question would be the fetch data before rendering the view

Comment: you can control the rendering of template elements with `v-if`: `v-if="fetchedData.length > 0"`

Comment: Yeah true. Would be one way to do it. Was just thinking this could be handled in the lifecycle hook.

Comment: there's no global method to prevent template rendering from lifecycle hooks (or any other component method). you have to define conditions in template as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could wrap everything in a simple `if` `fetchedData` has something see everything, otherwise not:

```
 <template>
   <div id="app">
     <div v-if="fetchedData.length">
      <h1>My Data length: {{fetchedData.length}}</h1>
      <li v-for="value in fetchedData">{{value}}</li>
     </div>
   </div>
 </template>
```

if you want you can also add an `else`, that is, if nothing has arrived yet, instead of showing nothing enter a "loading" text or better a spinner like these:
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/spinner#spinners

therefore:

```
 <template>
   <div id="app">
     <div v-if="fetchedData.length">
      <h1>My Data length: {{fetchedData.length}}</h1>
      <li v-for="value in fetchedData">{{value}}</li>
     </div>
     <div v-else>
       Loading...
       //Or your spinner
     </div>
   </div>
 </template>
```